# int[] array contains definition in linq query throw error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

```
var query = _db.Mst_Users
            .Where(item => item.CustomerUserId == customerUserId)
            .Traverse(item => _db.Mst_Users.Where(parent => item.CustomerUserId == parent.ParentId))
            .Select(item =>Convert.ToString(item.CustomerUserId)).ToArray();
```

In the above query I'm getting `customerUserId`s in an array:

```
int[] ids = query;
```

From the above int array:

```
var getgroup = from item in _db.Mst_Group 
               where ids.Contains(item.CustomerUserId) 
               select item;
```

However, it shows the following error:

```
int[] does not contain a definition for Contains and the best extension method overload system.linq.iqueryable.contains<tsource>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ToList() instead of ToArray() in the first query.
It will return a `List<int>` that contains the "Contains" method

```
List<int> ids = query;
```